# Traverse a graph represented in an adjacency matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, traversal, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am wanting to use the depth-first and breadth-first methods for traversing a graph. I have done this on a simple list of nodes before, but I have never tried it with an adjacency matrix and I honestly don't even know where to start.

Here is my matrix:

```
999999999 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 999999999 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 999999999 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 3 3 999999999 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 999999999 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 999999999 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 999999999 0 0 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 8 3 3 0 999999999 0 8 8 0 3 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 999999999 0 3 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 8 0 999999999 0 0 0 0 3 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 3 0 999999999 0 0 0 0 3 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 999999999 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 999999999 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 999999999 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 999999999 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 1 0 999999999
```

Here is how I created this matrix (C#):

```
private static int[,] CreateMatrix()
        {
            int A = 0;
            int B = 1;
            int C = 2;
            int D = 3;
            int E = 4;
            int F = 5;
            int G = 6;
            int H = 7;
            int I = 8;
            int J = 9;
            int K = 10;
            int L = 11;
            int M = 12;
            int N = 13;
            int O = 14;
            int P = 15;

            int[,] matrix = new int[16, 16];

            matrix[A, B] = 1;
            matrix[A, C] = 1;
            matrix[B, D] = 3;
            matrix[B, E] = 1;
            matrix[C, D] = 3;
            matrix[C, F] = 1;
            matrix[D, H] = 8;
            matrix[E, G] = 1;
            matrix[E, H] = 3;
            matrix[F, H] = 3;
            matrix[F, I] = 1;
            matrix[G, J] = 3;
            matrix[G, L] = 1;
            matrix[H, J] = 8;
            matrix[H, K] = 8;
            matrix[H, M] = 3;
            matrix[I, K] = 3;
            matrix[I, N] = 1;
            matrix[J, O] = 3;
            matrix[K, P] = 3;
            matrix[L, O] = 1;
            matrix[M, O] = 1;
            matrix[M, P] = 1;
            matrix[N, P] = 1;


            matrix[B, A] = 1;
            matrix[C, A] = 1;
            matrix[D, B] = 3;
            matrix[E, B] = 1;
            matrix[D, C] = 3;
            matrix[F, C] = 1;
            matrix[H, D] = 8;
            matrix[G, E] = 1;
            matrix[H, E] = 3;
            matrix[H, F] = 3;
            matrix[I, F] = 1;
            matrix[J, G] = 3;
            matrix[L, G] = 1;
            matrix[J, H] = 8;
            matrix[K, H] = 8;
            matrix[M, H] = 3;
            matrix[K, I] = 3;
            matrix[N, I] = 1;
            matrix[O, J] = 3;
            matrix[P, K] = 3;
            matrix[O, L] = 1;
            matrix[O, M] = 1;
            matrix[P, M] = 1;
            matrix[P, N] = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] == 0)
                        matrix[i, j] = 0;

                    if (i == j)
                        matrix[i, j] = 999999999;

                }
            }

            return matrix;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Graph that this matrix represents:

[image]

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your adjacency matrix; why is it not a matrix of bools?

Comment: It is a weighted graph. I will post of picture of the graph that it represents.

Comment: Got it. Some people use adjacency graphs with a count to indicate *how many edges* are between two nodes, which doesn't really make sense in your scenario.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zYZ7MbgR for one of the possible implantation of Eric Lippert using Int32 instead of Vertex

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every problem in computer science *except one* can be solved by *adding more abstraction*.

Start by writing the breadth-first-traversal in the most abstract way possible:

```
void BreadthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, Vertex start)
{
    /* A miracle happens */
}
```

We have a method that does what we want. Except that it hasn't been written yet. So write it with *slightly less abstraction*:

```
void BreadthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, Vertex start)
{
    /* make a queue of vertices */
    /* make a mark set of vertices */
    /* enqueue and mark start */
    /* while the queue is not empty */
        /* dequeue a vertext */
        /* enqueue and mark all the unmarked neighbours of the vertex */
}
```

Keep on going, removing more and more abstraction.

```
void BreadthFirstTraversal(Graph graph, Vertex start)
{
    var queue = new VertexQueue();
    var markSet = new VertexMarkSet();
    queue.Enqueue(start);
    markSet.Add(start);
    while(queue.NotEmpty())
    {
        var vertex = queue.Dequeue();
        foreach(Vertex neighbour in graph.ListNeighbours(vertex))
        {
            if (!markSet.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                markSet.Add(neighbour);
                queue.Enqueue(neighbour);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

OK, now you've got an algorithm that will work for *any graph*, no matter what its representation internally. So all you have to do is write `ListNeighbours(Vertex)` and you're done. (Assuming that you already know how to write a queue and a set, or are willing to use the types that come with the base class library.) How are you going to do that?

You see how I used abstraction there?  I really don't care whether its an adjacency matrix or an adjacency list, all I care about is that the graph provides me the service of giving me the neighbours of a vertex.

So, how are you going to write `ListNeighbours(Vertex)` given your adjacency matrix?

Two possible solutions to investigate:

- Make the `Graph.ListNeighbours(Vertex)` method return a `List<Vertex>`. Construct the list and hand it out.
- Make it return `IEnumerable<Vertex>` and use `yield return` to yield a sequence of neighbouring vertices.

---

UPDATE: OK, so how do we actually make a sequence of neighbours out of an adjacency matrix?

Let's suppose that every vertex is numbered, so `Vertex` is really `int`; this is traditionally how things are done with adjacency matrices.  We want to take in a vertex -- an int -- and return a sequence of vertices that are its neighbours.

We have an array that has the property that `array[i, j]` is non-zero if vertex `j` is a neighbour of vertex `i`.

Again, start abstract and work your way towards implementation:

```
public List<int> ListNeighbours(int vertex)
{
    /* a miracle happens */
}
```

What do we need to do to make that miracle happen?

```
public List<int> ListNeighbours(int vertex)
{
    /* create a new list */
    /* for each vertex j in the graph */
        /* if j is a neighbour of i then add it to the list */
    /* return the list */
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `yield return` to create a sequence:

```
public IEnumerable<int> ListNeighbours(int vertex)
{
    /* for each vertex j in the graph */
        /* if j is a neighbour of i then yield return j */
}
```

`yield return` iterators tend to be simpler, but beginner programmers often have a hard time sussing out the control flow.  **Try writing it both ways and see how it goes.**

Comment: Haha yes, now that is my true question in this instance. :P

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is that one problem that can not be solved by adding more abstraction??

Comment: @JLott: "My program contains too much abstraction".

Comment: Alright.. I am not going to lie... I don't even know where to start with building this ListNeighbors<Vertex> method... I have tried looking it up, but Google is not the best in these situations.

Comment: @JLott: I've added some hints. When I was starting off as an intern, this is how I wrote all my programs, like you see here. Start by writing a method that does nothing but has the correct signature, then fill in a high-level description, then break it down into steps, and keep on breaking it down until I can actually write the code for each step.